# Unable to access an associative array value using $var['key'] in Laravel php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, function, class

My array `$lastLogin` is set, has type array and can be `dd()`.  Even the value can be `dd()`.

```
dd(gettype($lastLogin), $lastLogin, $lastLogin['timestamp'])
```

Output (dummy data):

```
"array"

array:7 [▼
  "id" => 1234
  "user_id" => 1234
  "role_id" => 1234
  "company_id" => 1234
  "timestamp" => "2023-08-22 12:03:52"
  "ip_address" => "0.0.0.0"
  "location" => "Not Found"
]

"2023-08-22 12:03:52"
```

However, if I try and set `$row[] = $lastLogin['timestamp']` then it can't find the index and returns the error:

```
"Undefined index: timestamp"
```

I can get it to work by putting it into a ternary, but why can't I directly access the index in the array?

```
$row[] = array_key_exists('timestamp', $lastLogin) ? $lastLogin['timestamp'] : '';
```

Code:

```
foreach ($this->users as $company_user) {

$row = []

// User login information
$lastLogin = Monitor::last_login($company_user->id);
$row[] = $lastLogin['timestamp'];
$row[] = $lastLogin['location'];
}
```

`Monitor::last_login` is a static function on my Monitor Class.

I have looked on stackoverflow but have only found spelling or syntax errors for this issue, have I missed something? Could this be something to do with when variables are set, considering it works when I put it into a ternary or function

Comment: So you're saying that `$lastLogin = Monitor::last_login($company_user->id);
$row[] = $lastLogin['timestamp'];` produces the "Undefined index" error, but `$lastLogin = Monitor::last_login($company_user->id); dd(gettype($lastLogin), $lastLogin, $lastLogin['timestamp']);` produces the expected output as you showed in the question? That really doesn't make sense. I would be surprised if anyone can reproduce this, to be honest.

Comment: Are you doing this in a loop? Is it possible your `dd()` is dumping the first iteration which has a timestamp value but when you run the loop without a `dd()` `Monitor::last_login($company_user->id)` eventually returns a null value or one without a `timestamp`?

Comment: Or is the offending code somewhere where the array is out of scope or has been changed by some other code.  Dropping one or 2 liners on us it is difficult to say what you are really doing in what order and where!!!!

Comment: @ADyson That's just what I thought when it first happened.

Comment: @JonWhite Yes a foreach loop iterating through all the company users

Comment: Change your `dd()` to `dump()` and it'll tell you what the row value is that's erroring, which will be the one one missing the timestamp key

Comment: `iterating through all of the company users`...ok so probably at least _one_ of them has missing values in the array, but not all. Hence why the ternary helps, because it checks that the key exists before trying to use it. Maybe your dd() shows results for one iteration, but not another. It would really help if you provided a [mre] of the issue, so we can see what might really be happening.

Comment: @JonWhite AMAZING! Thanks so much for spotting that. The first user has a time stamp, but 3rd one doesn't so it returned the error on that iteration. Big help.

Comment: @ADyson good advice will do that for future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `dd()` in loop i guess so the only data that is shoing is the one which related to first user among `$this->users`, and the error `Undefined index: timestamp` may be caused by other `user` among `$this->users` so to check your data that try this code :

```
$all = [];

foreach ($this->users as $company_user) {

    $lastLogin = Monitor::last_login($company_user->id);
    $all[] = $lastLogin;

}

dd($all); // here you have all the instances of $lastLogin related to all $this->users.
```

now you can check which instance doesn't have `timestamp`.